# Fhir client against hapi server never returns more than 2000 records

Tags: hl7-fhir, hapi-fhir

I'm using the .NET Fhir client against a Smile (hapi) CDR Fhir server.  I have 3235 patients that I'm trying to retrieve using the code below, but never get more than 2000 exactly.  I have tried adding headers using and not using the `no-cache` option.  I know the server has more records because I issue a `Patient/?_summary=count` that gives me the total number of records I'm expecting (3235).

I've disabled server cache, refreshed indexes, but always get exactly 2000 records.  I've also tried different methods of retrieving patients by using Get() verses Search() methods, but both come up with the same result.  Can anyone suggest another way to get the correct number of patients back or hints as to what I may be doing wrong?

```
var patients = new List<Patient>();
var bundle = (Bundle)client.Get("Patient");
while (bundle != null)
{
    patients.AddRange(bundle.Entry.Select(e => e.Resource as Patient));
    bundle = client.Continue(bundle);
}
```

I've tried using several variations of including the cache control header but counts remain the same.

```
client.OnBeforeRequest += (object sender, BeforeRequestEventArgs e) =>
{
    e.RawRequest.Headers.Clear();
    e.RawRequest.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/fhir+json;fhirVersion=4.0");
    e.RawRequest.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The server has the right to impose an upper limit of data it will return in a single call, regardless of how many records are requested by the client.  The only way to retrieve more data is to page through it using the 'next' link, as defined in the FHIR spec.

Comment: Note that if you're the one running the server, there should be a configuration parameter that lets you adjust this limit based on the expected needs of your clients and the hardware's ability to handle expected load.

Comment: The client.Continue statement in the code above is the method to page to the next result. So if the loop terminates after 2000 Patients when there should be more, this seems like a server error, but not the result of the page size limit.

Comment: Yea the server defaults to 50 per page and a maximum of 250 pages (which is way less than the number I'm expecting).  I am paging through as @MirjamBaltus pointed out so still wondering where the limitation is coming from.

Comment: @Geekn: The limit does not come from the FhirClient, which just uses the 'next' link in the Bundle to retrieve the results. To exit the loop, the last Bundle looked at will not have that. You could try to retrieve the second to last Bundle with Postman or curl, and page through by hand. If the server has a limit, that will stop quickly. If it doesn't and you keep getting Bundles with the 'next' link in it, this will probably mean that limiting is done somewhere in the middle. Or you could ask SmileCDR whether they have imposed such a limit.